# Dynamic subdomain with .htaccess (centOS)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos, subdomain

I have a dedicated server, on which I'm running several project. Lets say this is example.ro.
The server is running CentOS 6.
I've created a unix user 'dev' and a subdomain: dev.example.ro.

Lets say that I want to work on a project called 'cpl', and I have to test it live on this server (it is a php project).

I would like to use the subdomain dev.cpl.example.ro, and on the filesystem it would be under /home/dev/public_html/cpl folder.

How should I modify my .htaccess in the public_html folder in order to dynamically use subdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to edit the .htaccess file to achieve this. But you have to create a separate site in Apache server. To demonstrate I am using am ubuntu lamp server but I think you can do the same on your CentOS.

**Create a virtual site in Apache**

```
sudo nano -w /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf
```

paste the following into the file and make necessary changes

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName cpl.example.ro
 ServerAlias *.cpl.example.ro
 DocumentRoot /home/dev/public_html/cpl

<Directory />
 #Options FollowSymLinks
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Save the file. After that you need to enable the newly site.

```
sudo a2ensite example
service apache2 restart
```

Edit the host file to resolve the dev.cpl.example.ro

```
sudo nano -w /etc/hosts
```

add the following line to the end and save the file

```
127.0.0.1       dev.cpl.example.ro
```